# Remove New User Restriction Not Working

Tags: support, bug, status-norepro, new-users

Today I received a notification on StackOverflow stating that I have gained 10 reputation points and earned the privilege "Remove new User Restriction". I went through the explanation and eventually landed upon the following page.
https://stackoverflow.com/review

The page stated that I need 10 reputation points to do reviews and so I am not allowed to it.
But I do have 10 points and that is the very reason I was directed to this page.

Is there something more to this, or am I getting something wrong here?

Comment: same thing happened when you earn 20 reputation you get chat privileges , but you cant start the chat from the moment you get 20 reputation, it requires sometime for kind of refreshment. Any moderator can light on this topic more clearly.

Comment: Caching? Also, I think there was a problem with *exactly* 10 reputation. Get 11 and everything will work.

Comment: Yeah, you were right. When I got more than 10 points, I faced no such problems.

Comment: It has just happened to me, so the bug is not fixed yet

Comment: Peops are looking into this at the moment, just to give a miniature update of sorts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Confirmed! The new user restrictions - for review at least - are not removed when a user has exactly 10 reputation points.

Maybe the copy can be changed to "earned more than" if this is what was meant. Otherwise the behaviour seems faulty.

The post should probably be tagged as a bug to get the attention it deserves which incidentally is a bit harder to get since the problem only affects specific new users.

**EDIT**

Here is a screenshot of the issue:

[image]